# Is there a way to get all tf.variables used in a function?

Tags: tensorflow.js

Given a function, is there a way to extract the tensorflow variables that are used in it? (The framework must somehow do this when a function is passed to an optimizer)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand what you say exactly.

But If you are talking about getting value from tensor, there are some ways to do that.

`tensor.data()` and `tensor.dataSync()`

Reference:
https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.2/#tf.Tensor.data

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19959062)

Comment: I got it and thanks for your advices. I think it’s better to delete my answer. Are you okay with that?

Comment: I'd leave it Hyuck - it was flagged by someone so went into a review. That was just my opinion when reviewing it (and, seeing the question, I'd be tempted to re-evaluate); others may feel otherwise. If the consensus is the same as me, it will be automatically removed, though others are well within their rights to disagree and then this will stay :) To be honest, the question didn't give you much to work with, and I imagine that will end up being removed itself.